# Jooq cte with joins not compiling

Tags: java, common-table-expression, jooq

I need in cte with joins.
In doc https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-clause/ just short example w/o any `joins` and `where` term.

If I use `joins` the type of will be TableOnConditionStep but for org.jooq.DerivedColumnList4#as required Select and faced with comile time error

```
 method as in interface org.jooq.DerivedColumnList4 cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: org.jooq.ResultQuery<R>
[ERROR]   found: org.jooq.TableOnConditionStep<org.jooq.Record>
[ERROR]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
[ERROR]     (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableOnConditionStep<org.jooq.Record> cannot be converted to org.jooq.ResultQuery<R>)
```

```java
 CommonTableExpression cte = name("amd")
            .fields("contact_id", "created_date", "name", "type")
            .as(
                select(
                    HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID,
                    DSL.max(HISTORIES.CREATED_DATE),
                    CONTACTS.NAME,
                    CONTACTS.TYPE
                ).from(
                        dslContext.select(
                                DSL.max(HISTORIES.ID),
                                DSL.max(HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID)
                            ).from(HISTORIES)
                            .groupBy(HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID)
                    ).asTable("q1")
                    .join(HISTORIES)
                    .on(field("q1.id").eq(HISTORIES.ID))
                    .join(CONTACTS)
                    .on(DSL.coalesce(HISTORIES.CREATED_BY, HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID).eq(CONTACTS.ID))
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced a parenthesis. You wrote:

```java
).asTable("q1")
```

When you should have written

```java
.asTable("q1"))
```

It becomes more obvious when you assign the derived table to a local variable like so:

```java
Table<?> q1 = 
    select(max(HISTORIES.ID), max(HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID))
    .from(HISTORIES)
    .groupBy(HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID)
    .asTable("q1");
```

And then:

```java
...
.from(q1)
.join(HISTORIES)
...
```

Comment: if i close by parenthesis

```
Table<Record> v = name("q")
            .as(
                dslContext.select(
                    ADVERTISING_MAILING_HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID,
                    DSL.coalesce(ADVERTISING_MAILING_HISTORIES.CREATED_BY, ADVERTISING_MAILING_HISTORIES.CONTACT_ID),
                    ADVERTISING_MAILING_HISTORIES.CREATED_DATE,
                    CONTACTS.NAME,
                    CONTACTS.TYPE
                ).from(q1))
```

`v` will be a table not CTE so i can not use it by `with` statement
Its near but not the same